# Tabcontrol tab text is not completely showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, tabcontrol

I have an ASP.NET tabcontrol and the text on the tabs is not showing completely.

See here:[image]

The live example can be seen here: http://www.telefonievergelijken.nl/test.aspx

I tried fixing it with changing the line-height of the body class (which actually I don't want to alter) and the height of the span on the tab label, which then shows the full text, but then I can't seem to get the text to show completely while also keeping the tab label connected to the actual tab it's showing, as can bee seen here, which is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase height in rule in file WebResource.axd on line 11

```
.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_tab {
    height: 21px;
    ...
}
```